# How to differentiate two web applications's mail in coldfusion 9 undelivered mail folder?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

There are any configuration in coldfusion application server?

Comment: i have 2 application running in my coldfusion 9 server and get
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#UndelivrMailLocation#" name="qEmailID" filter="*.cfmail" > to my application now when i see this mail i've got both of applications mail in my any of applications
so i want to see only according application's mails..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is an option to identify apps that send emails in cf administrator.

You may have to use the <cfmailparam> tag in sending emails to identify the application:

```
<cfmailparam name="x-app" value="name_of_my_application">
```

Then you'll have to examine the contents of the text file to determine which application sent the email.